# MIN Vs MAX function in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I am running below two queries but the run time is quite different for both. Could you please advise where it is going wrong.

Below query is giving output in less than 20 secs

```
select MAX(last_mod_date) last_mod_date
from dbo.raw
where prog_id like '198.A-2006%'
and dp_cat='SCIENCE'
```

Below query is giving output in 5-7 mins (sometimes more than 10 mins)

```
select MIN(last_mod_date) last_mod_date
from dbo.raw
where prog_id like '198.A-2006%'
and dp_cat='SCIENCE'
```

I tried doing update stats, reorg index which is on the column last_mod_date. But I don't see any benefit from these actions. Please find the attached execution plan of MIN query.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/st3uE.jpg)

Comment: Can you [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)s please?

Comment: Hello Larnu, thanks for responding. I have already attached the execution plan of MIN query. please let me know if you need any other details.

Comment: That's an image, and it's not of *both* the plans. *Can you [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)s please?*

Comment: Hello Larnu, please find the plans in below links https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkzBPVVSq    ---- MIN plan

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkXwPN4S5  ---- MAX plan

Comment: There's a **significant** number key lookups in your `MIN` compared to the `MAX` (21664749 and 243917 respectively). That might be due to a cached plan. What index(es) do you have you your table? The fact that it's doing a scan, followed by a keylookup suggests you don't have a covering index. You would at least want an index on `prog_id` and `dp_cat` that `INCLUDE`s `last_mod_date` for the above query.

Comment: The execution plan is scanning your index on last_mod_date. Depending on your query (MIN or MAX), it will traverse it in ascending or descending order. Then, for each entry, it does a key look up to check if the row has the prog_id and dp_cat that you require. When it finds a match, the query is finished.

Apparently, the first match is 21,662,749 entries from the top, while the last match is 243,941 from the bottom.

Your query would benefit from an index on (dp_cat, prog_id)

Comment: Thank you so much for your advise, after creating composite index on prog_id,dp_cat and last_mod_date the results are quite faster. In fact I can see the results within 1 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Create a compound index on these three columns: prod_id, dp_cat, last_mod_date. That will make your query fast: The server will random access the BTREE index to the correct values of the first two columns. Then, because it need only find the MIN of the third column, there will be the answer to the query. It will also serve for the MAX. The generalization of it is called a loose index scan.

As for why your two queries, without that index, are so different? It's hard to tell without seeing *both* execution plans. Actual Execution Plans will be the most helpful. In SSMS, right click in the query window and then choose Active Execution Plan. Then run the query.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, after creating the composite index I can see the derived results. Once again thank you :)